# How to set the paragraph to bottom of the images?

Tags: html, css

**This is my css :**

```
div#outerdiv
{
/*    padding:10px:*/
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:#eaa6a6;
    position:absolute;

}
img#rcorners1
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #5A0065;
    margin:40% auto;
    display:block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
p#unknown
{
    margin:auto;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Inside the div i placed the image and trying to place the paragraph bottom to the image but it takes long space even if i gave **margin 0% auto;**

**This is Html:**

```
<div id="outerdiv">

        <img id="rcorners1" src="img/man.png" alt="unknown number">             </img>
        <p id="unknown">UNKNOWN NUMBER</p>

    </div>
```

**ScreenShot:**
[image]

Comment: create a fiddle. Give it a specific height so it will not inherit the parent

Comment: @Katana ok bro  i will try

Comment: @Katana even if i gave specific height not working

Comment: did you remove the margin:auto?

Comment: @Katana yeah removed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix you `img` tag, `img` does not have closing tag. It should be

```
<img id="rcorners1" src="img/man.png" alt="unknown number" />
```

```css
div#outerdiv
{
/*    padding:10px:*/
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:#eaa6a6;
    position:absolute;

}

img#rcorners1
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #5A0065;
    margin:40% auto 0 auto;
    display:block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
p#unknown
{
    margin:auto;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}

/* if you want to have your bottom margin still 40%*/


/*p#unknown {
    margin-bottom: 40%;  
}*/
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv">

    <img id="rcorners1" src="img/man.png" alt="unknown number" />
    <p id="unknown">UNKNOWN NUMBER</p>

</div>
```

Actually `img` tag is taking `margin-bottom: 40%` which you need to make `0`.

```
img#rcorners1{
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #5A0065;
 margin:40% auto 0 auto; // margin-bottom: 0;
 display:block;
 width: 25%;
 height: 25%;
}
```

Comment: i gave up vote but instead of bottom 0 need something for eg below image with out space i want text is it possible

Comment: @KishoreKumar sure

Comment: @KishoreKumar Checkout updated solution, see if its implemented correctly.

Comment: wait a minute bro i will check